# При запуске sshd выдаёт ошибку

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssh

ввожу команду

```
sshd
```

выдаёт

```
sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path
```

скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
у меня wsl
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 4):

Буквально сообщение означает, что нужно вызывать полным путём: `/usr/sbin/sshd`

Но на самом деле всё сложнее. Скорее всего, вы увидите что-то вроде

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

`sshd` - это системный сервис. Его нужно запускать от имени рута как

```
sudo systemctl start sshd.service
```

**UPDATE**

В WSL (Windows Services for Linux) нет поддержки `systemd`, поэтому запускать `sshd` нужно старым добрым способом

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Может такое случиться, что пакеты были установлены криво, и `sshd` не сгенерировал ключи сервера и конфиги. Тогда их можно перегенерировать командой

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Comment: неработает, выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Узел выключен
```

Comment: @FIFIFiSKA сорри, только сейчас разглядел скриншот - вы в терминале Windows. В WSL не поддерживается systemctl. Вам нужна команда `sudo service ssh start`. Но для начала проверьте `sudo service ssh status` - может быть сервис уже запущен.

Comment: ввёл данную команду: 

* Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                                sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
                                                                                                     [fail]

Comment: @FIFIFiSKA `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` для генерации ключей сервера.

Comment: Вроде как в каких-то последних версиях WSL добавили полноценную поддержку systemd (но я лично ещё не проверял)

Answer (score 0):

/usr/sbin добавь в переменную окружения $PATH

```
        export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: Если вы внимательно прочитаете текст ошибки, то поймёте, что это никак не поможет